# Ionic 2 *ngFor loop if index 3

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my sidemenu template, I am using a ngFor loop to display all the items. Please see below:-

```
 <ion-item menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let page of pages" (click)="openPage(page)">
  <ion-icon [name]="page.icon" item-left></ion-icon>
  {{page.title | translate}}
  </ion-item>
```

But I want one menu item that will have a different callback function, given below: -

```
<ion-item menuClose ion-item (click)="openAnotherPage(136379)">
  <ion-icon name="home" item-left></ion-icon>
  New Menu
  </ion-item>
```

But the problem is I want the menu item that will call openAnotherPage in 3rd position.

Currently 'page' having 8 rows and I am unable to invoke my 'New Menu' item in between the loop.

Is it possible to check for index and update callback function and menu name?

```
 <ion-item menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let page of pages" **Like if index 3 **(click)="AnotheropenPage(page)" **and for the rest** (click)="openPage(page)">
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `openPage(page)` method can be configured in the `app.component.ts` file.

you can pass the index from the `app.html`

```
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index" (click)="openPage(p,i)"
```

Then in `app.component.ts` you can control the function based on the index passed in

```
openPage(page,index) {
   this.rootPage = index != 3 ? page : AnotherPage;
   // AnotherPage can also be a method like this.anotherPage(136379);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use ternary operator here.

```
(click)="index === 3 ? AnotheropenPage(page): openPage(page)"
```

Or you can shift this conditional logic as component method itself.

[**Sample Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DgMYuT4GkyeCNUsuGpP1?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pages; let i=index">
 <ion-item menuClose ion-item  *ngIf='i ==3' (click)="AnotheropenPage(page)">
 <ion-item menuClose ion-item  *ngIf='i !==3' (click)="openPage(page)">
</div>
```

you can try this

> PS:- i am taking `div` here as parent container , i am not familier with ionic so please make appropriate changes